# Pandas `RollingGroupby` aggregation destroys index

Tags: pandas, group-by, rolling-computation

The `agg` aggregation function works unexpectedly for `pandas.core.window.rolling.RollingGroupby` objects, which are created when a `groupby` operation is chained with `rolling` operation.

When using a single aggregation function, the result is what I expect: the index contains the group label as well as the DataFrame's original index labels.  For example:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({"data": [1,2,3,4,5]})
time = pd.date_range(start="1-1-2023", end="1-5-2023")
grp = pd.Series(["A", "A", "B", "B", "A"])
roll_gb = data.groupby(by=grp).rolling(window="2D", center=False, min_periods=1, on=time)

print(roll_gb.agg("mean"))

     data
A 0   1.0
  1   1.5
  4   5.0
B 2   3.0
  3   3.5
```

But if I aggregate with multiple functions, the original index is destroyed and replaced with the index used in the `on` argument to the `rolling` call.  Showing a list of aggregation functions with just `"mean"` for simplicity:

```py
print(roll_gb.agg(["mean"]))
             data
             mean
A 2023-01-01  1.0
  2023-01-02  1.5
  2023-01-05  5.0
B 2023-01-03  3.0
  2023-01-04  3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-line way to keep the index using Pandas [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```py
df = pd.concat(
    [roll_gb.agg(func) for func in ("mean", "sum")], axis=1, keys=["mean", "sum"]
).droplevel(1, axis=1)
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output

     mean  sum
A 0   1.0  1.0
  1   1.5  3.0
  4   5.0  5.0
B 2   3.0  3.0
  3   3.5  7.0
```